# Python: how to sum all value with different name from dict in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

i want to print the student scores,
i tried using `count` but it doesn't work

```
student_data = [{
"name":"Dos",
"Math":20,
"History":50,
"Science":60,},
{
"name":"moris",
"Math":20,
"History":50,
"Science":80,
}]

print(student_data)
name_search = str(input("Enter the student name: "))
for student in student_data:
    if student["name"] == name_search:
        print(student)
        dak = sum(student)
        print("Total:",dak)
```

My output:

```
Enter the student name: Dos
{'name': 'Dos', 'Math': 20, 'History': 50, 'Science': 60}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/New folder/tanya.py", line 18, in <module>
    dak = sum(student)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Desired out put:

```
Enter the student name: Dos
{'name': 'Dos', 'Math': 20, 'History': 50, 'Science': 60}
Total:130
```

should i make new if statement or i use the wrong statement?

Comment: Dictionaries iterate over the keys. You're computing the sum of the class names, not the scores

Comment: Not to mention, there is no way for Python to know that you *don't* want to include `'Dos'` in the summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a `sum_scores()` function to do what you want.

```
student_data = [{
"name":"Dos",
"Math":20,
"History":50,
"Science":60,},
{
"name":"moris",
"Math":20,
"History":50,
"Science":80,
}]

print(student_data)

name_search = str(input("Enter the student name: "))

def sum_scores(student):
    total_score = 0
    for key, val in student.items():
        if type(val) == int:
            total_score += val
    return total_score

for student in student_data:
    if student["name"] == name_search:
        print(student)
        dak = sum_scores(student)
        print("Total:",dak)
```

Here's the output:

```
Enter the student name: Dos
{'name': 'Dos', 'Math': 20, 'History': 50, 'Science': 60}
Total: 130
```

`sum_scores()` first checks whether the value of `student` is of type `int`. If it is, it adds the value to `totoal_score`. At the end of the execution, it returns the sum of all the values that are of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter first which value type is `integer`, then sum all of it with `sum()` function. You can do it like this

```
name_search = str(input("Enter the student name: "))
for student in student_data:
    if student["name"] == name_search:
        print(type(student['Math']))
        dak = sum([value for value in student.values() if type(value) == int])
        print("Total:",dak)
```

The result is as follow

```
Enter the student name: Dos
{'name': 'Dos', 'Math': 20, 'History': 50, 'Science': 60}
Total: 130
```

Comment: ty for make it simple and easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

`Sum` will not work for your case since it is meant to add up numbers. It doesn't meant that sum cant be used with a dictionary but simply when it is used, all the iterables must be a number (int or float). Also, that aside, if you simply use `sum(dict)`, you will be summing up all the keys of the dictionary. For example

```
scores = { 10: 'math', 20: 'science', 30: "English"}
print(sum(scores))
```

Will result in `60`

As for `count`, it is used in a list or string and only returns the number of times the specific element appears in the list. For example

```
lst = ['math', 'science', 'english', 'math']
print(lst.count('math'))
```

Will print out `2`

As for your code, you could iterate through all the values of your dictionary and check if they are an int or float. Then total it if it is.

```
student_data = [{
"name":"Dos",
"Math":20,
"History":50,
"Science":60,},
{
"name":"moris",
"Math":20,
"History":50,
"Science":80,
}]

print(student_data)
name_search = str(input("Enter the student name: "))
for student in student_data:
    if student["name"] == name_search:
        print(student)
        dak = 0
        for value in student.values():
            if type(value) == int or type(value) == float:
                dak += value
        print("Total:",dak)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your big mistake is not understanding how the sum function in python works. The sum() function only takes a list of numbers and adds them together, you can read more here: https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/sum/

Also in python and I am guessing most programming languages you can not add strings with numbers, numbers are items that can be mathematically manipulated not strings, unless you use variables to hold numeric values.

Also to add elements that are numbers from a dictionary you must select them first, you select an element from a dictionary by using it's key name, and remember to sum them they must contain numeric values ej.

to read more about dictionaries in python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

## Our dictionary here

data = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

## Here we create a list of numbers from the values of the data dictionary

list_of_numbers = [ data['a'], data['b'], data['c'] ]

## Now we can add them with the sum() function

sum(list_of_numbers)

## result of sum function

> > 6

So in your code it should look like this:

```
student_data = [{
"name":"Dos",
"Math":20,
"History":50,
"Science":60,},
{
"name":"moris",
"Math":20,
"History":50,
"Science":80,
}]


print(student_data)
name_search = str(input("Enter the student name: "))
for student in student_data:
    if student["name"] == name_search:
        print(student)
        scores = [student['Math'], student['History'], student['Science']]
        total_score = sum(scores)
        print("Total:", total_score)
```

Comment: Ty for the explanation it help me a lot